# Sequences of sets, liminf and limsup

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

If $A_i$ is a sequence of sets, define$$\liminf_i A_i = \bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \bigcap_{i = j}^\infty A_i, \quad \limsup_i A_i = \bigcap_{j = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{i = j}^\infty A_i.$$How do I see that$$\liminf_i A_i = \{x : x \in A_i \text{ for all but finitely many }i\},$$$$\limsup_i A_i = \{x : x \in A_i \text{ for infinitely many }i\}?$$

Comment: Show that any x belonging to the LHS belongs to the RHS, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

$x \in \liminf_i A_i$ iff $\exists j_0$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{i=j_0}^{\infty} A_i$ (by the definition of a union). So in total we know that

$$x \in \liminf_i A_i \text{  iff  }\, \exists j_0 : \forall i \ge j_0 : x \in A_i$$

which exactly says that $x$ lies in all but finitely many of the $A_i$: the only possible exceptions are the $A_i$ with $i < j_0$, which is a finite set. And if we only have finitely many exceptions, let $j_0$ be 1 larger than the largest index $i$ with $x \notin A_i$ (or $0$ if no such $i$ exists at all).

For the lim sup we can do a similar expansion of the definition:

$$x \in \limsup_i A_i \text{ iff }\, \forall j: \exists i \ge j: x \in A_i$$

which in words means that for every index $j$ there will always be a larger index $i$ such that $x \in A_i$, which means the indices of $A_i$ that contain $x$ form an unbounded set in the natural numbers: apply it to $j=0$, we get some $i_0 \ge 0$ with $x \in A_{i_0}$. Then apply the definition to $i_0 + 1$ and we get an index $i_1 \ge i_0 + 1$ such that $x \in A_{i_1}$, and then to $j = i_1 + 1$ to get $i_2$ etc. By recursion we define $i_k$ (strictly increasing) with $x \in A_{i_k}$ for all $k$. And reversely if the set of indices is infinite, then for any given $j$, there are only finitely many sets $A_i$ with $i < j$, so there are plenty of $i$ left (necessarily $\ge j$) that contain $x$.